# Laravel having query

Tags: laravel

This is my query:

```
Order::query()
            ->join('dispatcher_contractor_pays', function ($join) {

                 $join->on('orders.id', '=', 'dispatcher_contractor_pays.order_id')
                     ->where('dispatcher_contractor_pays.contractor_type', '=', Contractor::class);
             })
             ->join('order_workers_value_added', function ($join) {

                 $join->on('orders.id', '=', 'order_workers_value_added.order_id')
                     ->where('order_workers_value_added.worker_type', '=', Contractor::class);
             })
             ->having('orders.amount',  '>', DB::raw('SUM(order_workers_value_added.amount) 
                       + SUM(dispatcher_contractor_pays.sum)'));
```

And get error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.amount' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `orders` inner join `dispatcher_contractor_pays` on `orders`.`id` = `dispatcher_contractor_pays`.`order_id` and `dispatcher_contractor_pays`.`contractor_type` = Modules\Dispatcher\Entities\Directories\Contractor inner join `order_workers_value_added` on `orders`.`id` = `order_workers_value_added`.`order_id` and `order_workers_value_added`.`worker_type` = Modules\Dispatcher\Entities\Directories\Contractor where `status` not in (open) and `orders`.`contractor_id` = 13 and `domain_id` = 1 and exists (select * from `dispatcher_contractors` inner join `order_workers` on `dispatcher_contractors`.`id` = `order_workers`.`worker_id` where `orders`.`id` = `order_workers`.`order_id` and `order_workers`.`worker_type` = Modules\Dispatcher\Entities\Directories\Contractor and `dispatcher_contractors`.`deleted_at` is null) and `orders`.`deleted_at` is null having `orders`.`amount` > SUM(order_workers_value_added.amount) + SUM(dispatcher_contractor_pays.sum))"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Tables structure

orders : `|id,amount,status, e.t.c |`

dispatcher_contractor_pays: `|id,date,sum,order_id,contractor_type, e.t.c |`

order_workers_value_added: `|id,amount,order_id,worker_type,worker_id, e.t.c |`

Comment: I'm gonna take a quick look at the query, but just putting it out there, you may want to use the Eloquent Query Builder provided by the Laravel framework. It's one of the most powerful features of the framework!

Comment: Can you post the structure of your tables? My bet is that your table is either called `order` rather than `orders` or you are missing a column

Comment: No columns missing

Comment: What if you remove the `->having` statement and just `get or first`, and diedump `dd()` the result of the query? What is that result?

Comment: Just a list of all orders.

Comment: I think the agregations should be on the left side and should be selected. Not sure.

Comment: @Nikolay but is the orders amount part of that list?

Comment: Usually Laravel outputs the whole failed query in the error message. Could you add this to your question too?

Comment: @Dan added in question.